# Controlling fan speed acording to temp of the on board thermometer Raspberry pi pico

Tags: pi-pico

How do I control the fan speed based on the temperature of the on board thermometer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: WHY? It would be possible, BUT the prospect of a Pico overheating is negligible. I suggest you monitor temperature to see what maximum you reach.

Comment: No. This is not a write my code for me site. As this is a pointless exercise you won't find a ready made solution. If you want to do this work out 1. how to read temperature 2. how to control a fan 3. Code to combine. If you have problems ask a specific question about your code.

Comment: the fan is a 3 wire can i conect thired wire to gpio

Comment: yes you can ... check the fan datasheet to determine the purpose of the 3rd wire in the fan that you have

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the temperature to a PWM duty cycle. To do this you determine the minimums and maximums of both temperature and RPM. Then determine a minimum RPM (PWM value). The minimum will be the slowest you will go unless turning it off. This correlates to your minimum PWM duty cycle. Then determine the maximum temperature, this correlates to the maximum PWM duty cycle probably 100%. You can test this with a LED to see if the software is working. On the output you need a power supply that will supply enough current to run the fan plus some more for starting. That power supplies output voltage needs to be the same as the fan or you can use a converter (SEPIC, Buck, Boost) that will convert to the voltage you need.

Connect the ground of the fan power supply to the ground of the Pi and the source of the MOSFET. Place an optional (only needed if you want it off unless you are controlling it) 10K resistor from the port pin to ground. Place a 50 Ohm resistor from the port pin to the gate of the N-Channel MOSFET. Be sure the MOSFET is on at about 2.5V (Vgs). Connect the + of the fan to the fan power supply +. That is it.

NOTE: there are many drawings that show this similar circuit but in error place the 10K from the gate to ground, this is wrong it robs voltage from the MOSFET reducing its current capacity. It forms a voltage divider and you only have about 3V3 to start with.

On the fans I have the third wire yellow is an output that pulses in relationship to the number of revelations the fan makes. I get two pulses per revolution. For example if you have the fan spinning at 3000 RPM, you would measure a 100 Hz pulse rate (3000 rev/min / 60 s * 2 pulses/rev = 100 pulses/sec). The pulse on mine is a symmetrical square wave, not a pwm signal.

Comment: how do i make software

Comment: can i just wire the third wire to a gpio pin

Comment: Yes, as long as it is an input.  The third wire is **not** a control, it uses PWM to indicate the speed of the fan right now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to playing with Raspberry Pi but perhaps what I did may be useful to you.

First off, this is for a Raspberry Pi 4B. The fan that came with the *over priced* Starter Kit is a 3 wire PWM fan. PWM stands for **P**ulse **W**idth Modulation and is used to switch the fan ON and OFF in whatever duty cycle you like to in essence control the fan speed. I chose to go with a simple ON/OFF.

The PWM Kit fan is low enough power to run directly from the GPIO pins without needing any external circuitry. I understand all of the Raspberry Pi versions have compatible pins so I **assume** this will work for the Pico but don't know for sure.

I hooked the fan to: 5V, Ground, and GPIO 14 (Pin 8).

The fan started immediately running and stayed on.

**I used Python for the code. I'm not covering installation of Python and the necessary libraries.**

First piece of code, **fan-off.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Raspberry Pi fan off
import os
import datetime
import signal
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pin = 14 # The pin ID, edit here to change it
DEBUG = True  # Print debug messages

def debug(message):
    if DEBUG:
        dateTimeStr = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        print(" ")
        print(dateTimeStr)
        print(message)
    return()


def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    return()
    
def getCPUtemperature():
    res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
    temp =(res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))
    debug("temp is {0}".format(temp))
    return temp
        
def fanOFF():
    debug("Fan off ...")     #Debug
    setPin(False)
    return()
    
def getTEMP():
    CPU_temp = float(getCPUtemperature())
    fanOFF()
    return()

def setPin(mode): # # Probably unnecessary but I haven't tested removal
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.output(pin, mode)
    return()
        
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
setup() 
getTEMP()
```

Second piece of code, **fan-on.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Raspberry Pi fan off
import os
import datetime
import signal
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pin = 14 # The pin ID, edit here to change it
DEBUG = True  # Print debug messages

def debug(message):
    if DEBUG:
        dateTimeStr = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        print(" ")
        print(dateTimeStr)
        print(message)
    return()


def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    return()
    
def getCPUtemperature():
    res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
    temp =(res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))
    debug("temp is {0}".format(temp))
    return temp
        
def fanON():
    debug("Fan ON ...")     #Debug
    setPin(True)
    return()
    
def getTEMP():
    CPU_temp = float(getCPUtemperature())
    fanON()
    return()

def setPin(mode):     # Probably unnecessary but I haven't tested removal
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.output(pin, mode)
    return()
        
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
setup() 
getTEMP()
```

Now we put it all together to control the fan based upon temperature.

Based upon a few experiments I chose 55 degrees C to turn on the fan and 50 C to turn it off. Two different values prevents chattering the fan on and off. You may want different temperatures for your environment. I set the code up to run in CRON every two minutes. There is some instruction on how to debug CRON for your environment.

Third piece of code, **run-fan.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Add PATH statement to CRONTAB if running CRON
#     CRONTAB dumps all output and errors to a log file:
#     The commented out cron entry after the path is an environment debug example.
#
#     # Run Fan Controller every 2 minutes
# 
#     # m h  dom mon dow   command
#     PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/osmc/bin:/opt/vc/bin
#     #* * * * * source ~/.bashrc; echo $PATH >> ~/crontab_log.txt 2>&1
#     */2 * * * * ~/run-fan.py >> ~/crontab_log.txt 2>&1
#     
#         Move all "Prints" to a single debug control
#         Take out loop and use CRON instead  (DEBUG False for normal CRON use)
#         Set Upper & Lower Temp limits to reduce unnecessary toggling of fan

import os
import datetime
import signal
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pin = 14 # The pin ID, edit here to change it.
onTMP = 55  # The maximum temperature in Celsius after which we turn ON the fan.
offTMP = 50 # The low temperature in Celsius after which we turn OFF the fan.
DEBUG = True  # Print debug messages. Change to False for normal use.

def debug(message):
    if DEBUG:
        dateTimeStr = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        print(" ")
        print(dateTimeStr)
        print(message)
    return()


def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    return()
    
def getCPUtemperature():
    res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
    temp =(res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))
    debug("temp is {0}".format(temp))
    return temp
    
def fanON():
    debug("Fan on ...")     #Debug
    setPin(True)
    return()
    
def fanOFF():
    debug("Fan off ...")     #Debug
    setPin(False)
    return()
    
def getTEMP():
    CPU_temp = float(getCPUtemperature())
    if CPU_temp > onTMP:
        fanON()
    elif CPU_temp < offTMP:
        fanOFF()
    return()

def setPin(mode): # Probably unnecessary but I haven't tested removal
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.output(pin, mode)
    return()
        
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
setup() 
getTEMP()
```

To help you determine the temperatures you want for On & Off, here is a fourth piece of code, **temp-check.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#

import os
import datetime
import signal
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

DEBUG = True  # Print debug messages

def debug(message):
    if DEBUG:
        dateTimeStr = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        print(" ")
        print(dateTimeStr)
        print(message)
    return()
    
def getCPUtemperature():
    res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
    temp =(res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))
    debug("temp is {0}".format(temp))
    return temp
        
def getTEMP():
    CPU_temp = float(getCPUtemperature())
    return()
        
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
getTEMP()
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi their thanks for the tip yes this does work on the pico and is actully very similar to what i did thanks but thanks for the help and tip